# Linear algebra story problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A plane flies on a trip at a speed of 250 miles per hour. On the return trip it flies 412 miles per hour. The speed difference is a result of the wind blowing in one direction at the same speed during both trips. Determine the speed of the plane in still air and the speed of the wind.

Comment: Please show how to solve story probem

Comment: Please explain why you are incapable of solving story problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $n$ to be the speed of the wind. Assume that the speed of the plane is constant, and call it $x$.

Then on the first trip, $$250 = x-n$$

On the return trip, $$412 = x +n$$

Rearrange both equation to isolate n, then solve for x:

$$x+250 = -x + 412$$
$$2x = 162$$
$$ x = 81$$

Using this $x$, you find that $n$ is equal to 331 mph from the direction of the destination location to the original location.